# How to keep track of points in a Point-Based Game ? IN PYTHON

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to keep track of the number of points in the game depending on user input.So if the user puts in input of 3 the i want to add 1 to that and display a text regarding that and at the same time the other users point must not be added i.e if one user puts an input only his point gets increased by 1 and the others remain constant and vice versa.I also want the max input to be 100 and nil/no point input to be 0.Please Help.Thank You

Comment: What have you tried already? What problems are you having?

Comment: The question is overly broad. If you want to keep track of something, use a variable. It isn't clear what your question actually is. Perhaps it might help to read a python tutorial.